# Extracting Parenthetical Data Using Regex

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a small sub that extracts parenthetical data (including parentheses) from a string and stores it in cells adjacent to the string:

```
Sub parens()
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    s = ActiveCell.Value
    ary = Split(s, ")")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary) - 1
        bry = Split(ary(i), "(")
        c.Add "(" & bry(1) & ")"
    Next i

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).NumberFormat = "@"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = c.Item(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

I am now trying to replace this with some Regex code.  I am NOT a regex expert.  I want to create a pattern that looks for an open parenthesis followed by zero or more characters of any type followed by a close parenthesis.
I came up with:

```
\((.+?)\)
```

My current new code is:

```
Sub qwerty2()

    Dim inpt As String, outpt As String
    Dim MColl As MatchCollection, temp2 As String
    Dim regex As RegExp, L As Long

    inpt = ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox inpt
    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "\((.+?)\)"
    Set MColl = regex.Execute(inpt)
    MsgBox MColl.Count
    temp2 = MColl(0).Value
    MsgBox temp2

End Sub
```

The code has at least two problems:

- It will only get the first match in the string.*(Mcoll.Count is always 1)*
- It will not recognize zero characters between the parentheses. *(I think the **.+?** requires at least one character)*

Does anyone have any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, RegExp *Global* property is *False*. You need to set it to *True*.

As for the regex, to match zero or more chars as few as possible, you need `*?`, not `+?`. Note that both are *lazy* (match as few as necessary to find  a valid match), but `+` requires at least one char, while `*` allows matching zero chars (an empty string).

Thus, use

```
Set regex = New RegExp
regex.Global = True
regex.Pattern = "\((.*?)\)"
```

As for the regex, you can also use

```
regex.Pattern = "\(([^()]*)\)"
```

where `[^()]` is a *negated character class* matching any char but `(` and `)`, zero or more times (due to `*` quantifier), matching as many such chars as possible (`*` is a greedy quantifier).

Comment: Thanks again! .....................Perfect!  **Thanks for the explanation as well !**